# Circular progress indication

Tags: c++, qt

Im searching for an circular progress indication Widget for Qt5 like this:
http://anthonyterrien.com/knob/

Is there something similar or is it possible to do this in Qt?

I want to set the percentage manually, it shouldn't be a spinning circle or something like that

Comment: No. Nothing like that. At least not in standard Qt. QDial comes close, but is no progress indicator. Perhaps it is easier to make something from scratch. It does not look too difficult. Functionality of QProgressBar and some custom drawing.

Comment: You might also reuse QSpinBox for functionality. But regardless what you choose... if you don't find a 3rd party solution, it is a paint job for you..... And I don't know why the 1st answer was removed... it was not wrong. :-(

Comment: If you don't mind using QML, you can take a look at Qt Knobs. https://github.com/ashish157/QtKnobs

Comment: Thank your Greenflow. I think QDial will work for my purpose. I just have to let it look a little bit different!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is very easy to write. You need just special `paintEvent()` and slot to `setProgress()`. Of course if you want to add more beauty, then you need spend some time, but here is example:

Header:

```
#ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QPaintEvent>

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);

signals:

public slots:
    void setProgress(int val);

protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *);

private:
    double progress;

};

#endif // WIDGET_H
```

cpp:

```
void Widget::setProgress(int val)
{
    progress = (double)val/100;
    //yes, it is not very good, the best approach is to
    //create something similar to QProgressBar
    this->update();
}


void Widget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
    QPainter p(this);

    QPen pen;
    pen.setWidth(7);
    pen.setColor(Qt::red);
    p.setPen(pen);

    p.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);

    QRectF rectangle(10.0, 20.0, 80.0, 80.0);
    //to understand these magic numbers, look drawArc method in Qt doc
    int startAngle = -90 * 16;
    int spanAngle = progress * 360 * 16;

    p.drawArc(rectangle, startAngle, spanAngle);

    p.drawText(rectangle,Qt::AlignCenter,QString::number(progress*100)+" %");
}
```

Usage:

```
Widget wd; 
wd.show();
QSlider sl;
sl.show();

QObject::connect(&sl,SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)),&wd,SLOT(setProgress(int)));
```

Result:

[image]

I showed here main idea, but I think that my code can be improved, for example add methods `setMinimum/Maximum` and `setValue`, as in `QProgressBar`, but I hope you will add additional functionality manually if you need this.